# bash script - delay between words echo command

Tags: bash, shell

How can I have a delay between words to simulate an actual human typing all in one horizontal line? For loops only display vertically as far as I know.

This pseudocode is what I have in mind:

```
    echo "hello" && sleep 1 && echo "world" && sleep 1 && echo "!"
```

Something like that.

Comment: What do you mean "for loops only display vertically"?  You can write a loop as `for i in a b c; do echo "$i"; done`, but I don't see how that addresses the question at all.  I guess you could do `for word in hello world \!; do echo "$word" && sleep 1; done`

Comment: Add `-n` to each `echo` but the last.

Comment: @pmf thnx, that did the trick

Comment: [tag:expect] can actually simulate typing, with delays between each character. For fun, run https://www.99-bottles-of-beer.net/language-expect-249.html

Comment: `echo -n "hello" && sleep 1 && echo -n " world" && sleep 1 && echo "!"`?

Answer (score 1):

This is actually quite a cool tool called `pv` standing for pipe viewer, but can simulate what you're looking for, I found the answer [here](https://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/4583/simulate-typing).

TL;DR:

`echo "You can simulate on-screen typing just like in the movies" | pv -qL 10`

A little longer answer:

`pv` allows you to monitor data sent through a pipe, hence pipe viewer. This is done visually and therefore it has visual monitoring capabilities. In your case we use

L - this limits the character transfer rate, bytes-per-second
q - quiet, otherwise you will a breakdown analysis of how long each package took to go through the pipe.

Comment: thnx, i tried it and really liked it. how would you add that to a shell script without the giving you the error 'Syntax error: "(" unexpected'?

Comment: When I ran it in a script it worked. Maybe edit the original question with an example script so we can try and debug it?

Comment: Do you have a shebang '/bin/bash' of some sort at the beginning of your script?

Comment: correct. line #!/bin/bash was there. could you please post your 2-liner? the shebang +  the pv command? so close yet so far away lol  this is what i have #!/bin/bash
echo "hello world" | pv -qL $[10+(-2 + RANDOM%5)]

Comment: i think i figured it out, i needed to run from the shell: /bin/bash test.sh   i was using just sh test.sh   --behavior i have never seen before. usually sh does it for me.  thank you for all your help